# Creating multiple tables in one SqlCe command not working

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-ce

I try to run the following code:

```
           SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine( connStr );
            engine.CreateDatabase( );

            SqlCeConnection conn = null;


            conn = new SqlCeConnection( connStr );
            conn.Open( );

            string eh =
@"Create table test(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, DateTest DATETIME);
Create table test2(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, DateTest DATETIME);";

            SqlCeCommand hm = new SqlCeCommand(eh, conn);
             hm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However when I try to do an ExecuteNonQuery I get the following exception:

> {There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token
>   line offset = 1,Token in error = Create ]}

Any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute each command separately.

If you want them to all succeed or fail together, then you need to wrap everything in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Like others said, the two commands need to be separated.  I believe that add `GO` between the two commands will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your second statement in create contains `table2` it should simply `table`

> Create **table** test2(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, DateTest
>   DATETIME);

**EDIT:** Since `table2` was a typo, I believe you have to execute both the command separately.